# Android app not updating when application is opened

Tags: android, google-play

I'm releasing a single app purpose that I update through google play store.

For those who do not know, a single app purpose is an app that is supposed to run **alone** on a device.

Therefore I give away the device the app, and **prevent** the users to use any other apps.

Anyway, I start the app automatically on boot. The devices reboot every day at 5 AM.

I've noticed that the google play store checks for updates when the device boots.

Unfortunately, it seems that the update won't perform while the app is opened.

**To this I have 2 questions** :

1. Is this odd behavior of update familiar to anybody (having the update not performing for the currently running apps)
2. How to solve this?

**PS**: I did think of updating the app versionCode on a third party server and if it's not up to date, close the app, let the update perform, then receive when the update is done performing to re-open the app.
But honestly, it feels like killing a fly with the bazooka.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should depend on external server for this purpose.

App not being updated when running in foreground makes sense because Google play is not supposed to stop a running app which is necessary for updating it.

I recommend you to use Firebase cloud messaging service for the purpose. You can easily send data to the device using FCM.